# Golang index template including

Tags: templates, go, go-templates

I have two templates in [my project](https://github.com/kaihendry/dc) like so:

```
var indextemplate = template.Must(template.New("").Parse(`<!DOCTYPE html>
<form action="/compare" method="post">
<input type="date" name="from" required>
<input type="submit">
</form>`))

var comparetemplate = template.Must(template.New("").Parse("Hours since {{.From}} are {{.Duration}}"))
```

I don't understand how to structure the code so I have the HTML template (with a head and `</html>` at the end) and just include those templates into the body.

I also don't quite understand what is best practice to structure the code so that the template matches the handler. Since IIUC you need to best compile the template outside the handler.

Comment: Why not using template files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you should know is that a value of [`template.Template`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template) can be a collection of multiple templates, see its [`Template.Templates()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Templates) method which returns this collection.

Each template in the collection has a unique name that it can be referred to by (see [`Template.Name()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Name)). And there is a `{{template "name" pipeline}}` action, and using that you can include other templates in a template, another template which is part of the collection.

See this example. Let's define 2 templates:

```
const tmain = `<html><body>
Some body. Now include the other template:
{{template "content" .}}
</body></html>
`
const tcontent = `I'M THE CONTENT, param passed is: {{.Param}}`
```

As you can see, `tmain` includes another template named `"content"`. You can use the [`Template.New()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.New) method (stressing: **method**, not to be confused with the func [`template.New()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#New) ) to create a new associated, named template that will be part of the template whose method you're calling. As a result, they can refer to each other, e.g. they can include each other.

Let's see code that parses these 2 templates into one `template.Template` so they can refer to each other (error check omitted for brevity):

```
t := template.Must(template.New("main").Parse(tmain))
t.New("content").Parse(tcontent)

param := struct{ Param string }{"paramvalue"}

if err := t.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "main", param); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/xs4Dw1ZEmw)):

```
<html><body>
Some body. Now include the other template:
I'M THE CONTENT, param passed is: paramvalue
</body></html>
```

#### Alternative

Also note that if you have many and bigger templates, this becomes less readable and maintainable. You should consider saving your templates as files, and you can use [`template.ParseFiles()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#ParseFiles) and [`template.ParseGlob()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#ParseGlob), both which can parse multiple files at once and they build the template collection from them, so they can refer to each other. The names of the templates will be the names of the files.

Comment: I have a problem in https://github.com/kaihendry/dc/commit/9fe0e8f60fa7bf3ad5fbef98d7ec54a7012c1dc3 where the included template is not being executed and the values filled in. So my output is just **Hours since are** which is wrong. What am I missing?

Comment: @hendry That is because you passed a `nil` pipeline to the included template. If you want to pass on the pipeline (the params), include it like this: `{{template "content" .}} `. I edited the answer and examples to show passing the pipeline.

Comment: Thank you! If anything could be better with https://github.com/kaihendry/dc RE templating... please let me know. I don't like separate templates since they aren't in the binary.